# External display no longer works since upgraded to Sonoma 14

Tags: macos, display, sonoma

Using MacBook Pro with M1 silicon (2020); Dell S2318Nc monitor with HDMI and VGA outputs. I was using HDMI to HDMI. I have a bar with various connectors on my computer. Using that to power the MBP and an external keyboard. Now my MBP doesn't recognize the Dell. Why?

Comment: does it works without the bar

Comment: You state *" HDMI to HDMI"*, but your Mac does not have a HDMI port. If you are connecting the monitor to the bar, then could you provide the make and model of the bar? If you are connecting the monitor to the Mac by some other means, could you detail the means?

Comment: I can not find your monitor listed at [Dell's website for manuals](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/products?app=manuals). However, I can find [examples](https://www.ebay.com/p/11042895666) where the same model monitor can be purchased used. So, I assume the model given in your question is correct. Do you have any idea how old the monitor is? I am trying to get an idea which [HDMI version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Versions) the monitor uses.